# WPF - Converting point, taking Windows scale factor into account

Tags: wpf, image, translation, scaling

I have written a small test app, in which I have an image, with a canvas over the top of it. The idea is that a user will be able to "draw" on the canvas. I have an image that is 839 pixels wide and 396 pixels high. I wrote code to capture the mouse position as I move it around the canvas, using e.GetPosition(this) inside the canvas.

The problem is, when I near the bottom-right corner of the image/canvas, I'm getting back position 559, 264, rather than position 839, 396. In other words, the values I'm getting back are scaled by 1.5, which is my Windows scale factor.

I've tried myCanvas.TranslatePoint() and myCanvas.PointFromScreen() and myCanvas.PointToScreen(). I don't want a screen-relative point; I want points relative to the image, not taking the Windows scaling factor into account.

If I simply multiply the values by 1.5, I get the bitmap-relative points that I'm looking for, but of course that's not a solution.

Is there a "Windows-approved" way to do this, short of reading the scaling factor from the registry and manually applying it? I'm not in UWP, so I can't use Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings (at least, I don't think I can). I need this to work for both Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I can't find a way to attach my solution to this question, but the entirety of my code is shown below. The only thing missing is the PNG file, but literally any image gives the same results.

```
 <Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="500"
        Width="900">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Stretch="None"
           Source="/BingMap.PNG"
           MouseMove="BackgroundImage_MouseMove"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="TB"
               Grid.Row="2" />
  </Grid>
</Window>

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace StackOverflow
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BackgroundImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      var pt = e.GetPosition(this);
      TB.Text = $"{pt.X:n0}, {pt.Y:n0}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show actual code? Handing coordinates could be quite complicated and many factors could affect it.

Comment: Sure thing. Attached is a sample project, that contains an image that is 839 pixels wide and 396 pixels tall. I'm running it on a computer with a monitor with 150% scaling. As I move the mouse around the image, I never see mouse points approaching an X coordinate of 839 or a Y coordinate of 396. Instead, X only goes to 839 / 1.5.

Comment: I noticed that `Stretch` is set None which results in exactly what Clemens explained. It is a different factor than monitor DPI. It depends on DPI information embedded in your image file. I guess it is 144 (839 / 144 * 96 = around 559). Your can check it in the Explorer.

Comment: I wish I could see the DPI, but going to File Explorer and selecting Properties for the image file (a PNG) shows me dimensions, bit depth, size, date information, file location, but no DPI. However, binding Width and Height aren't making any difference at all to the look, or the behavior, of the app. I think I found a solution, though, by manually scaling the mouse points by using:       

PresentationSource ps = PresentationSource.FromVisual(vis);
return ps.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;

I'm still testing that code.

Comment: To see embedded DPI, in the Explorer, open the properties of an image file -> Details -> Image -> Horizontal dpi, Veritical dpi. Then, don't mix them up with monitor DPI. In addition, what you mentioned is old way to get monitor DPI which is not reliable under per-monitor DPI environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image file certainly has different DPI than the standard 96, which is used by WPF's *device independent pixels*. The native, unstretched size in which a raster image is displayed is determined by its pixel dimensions each multiplied by 96/DPI.

You may get around this simply by binding an Image element's `Width` and `Height` to the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` of its `Source`.

```
<Image Source="..."
    Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Height="{Binding Source.PixelHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I added those bindings to my xaml, and I wasn't able to detect any difference in either the look or the behavior of my test app. I'm fine with the size of the image in the window (it was generated by screenshotting a different part of the screen, and the displayed image is identical in size to the screenshotted portion of the screen, as I would expect to see. I think I may have found a way to calculate the image-relative mouse points by using PresentationSource.FromVisual(...).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11

Comment: My apologies! You meant to set those two properties, and also remove Stretch=None. That does indeed appear to do most of what I need, though it has a side effect in the real test app I'm writing: I'm copying the image from a map that's on the left side of the screen, and if I copy an area, that's say, 2" square from the map, the bitmap that's displayed on the right side of the screen shows the image in a different size. Perhaps there's a similar property I can set in the map, of maybe users won't care about the size difference, but that's unrelated to this post. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have no idea of what you are doing when you copy bitmaps. For the Stretch, that was not in your question when I wrote the answer. The default is Uniform, and that should be working, as well as Fill or UniformToFill.