# How to properly align Canvas with the underlying Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, alignment

My application detects a foreign object (blob, cluster etc) in the live webcam image and displays object's outline on top of the image. To achieve that I employ `Image` and `Canvas` elements as follows:

```
<Border x:Name="ViewportBorder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="3" Background="AliceBlue" BorderBrush="Red">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="videoPlayer" Stretch="Uniform" MouseDown="videoPlayer_MouseDown"></Image>
        <Canvas x:Name="ObjectsCanvas"></Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

`Border` element in the above XAML is used just to draw a thick red line border around the `Grid` containing `videoPlayer` and `ObjectsCanvas`. `Stretch="Uniform"` is set to preserve image aspect ratio while being able it to stretch when application window gets maximized.

Every time the new frame arrives from the camera `videoPlayer.Source` gets updated with frame's bitmap whereas blob detection method yields a list of coordinates used for drawing a `Polyline`. The `Polyline` object is then added to `ObjectsCanvas` to be shown on top of the actual image frame.

Here's a part which draws the blob and adds it to the `ObjectsCanvas.Children`:

```
private void DrawBlob(List<Point> corners)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var myPolyline = new Polyline();
        myPolyline.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
        myPolyline.StrokeThickness = 4;
        myPolyline.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;
        myPolyline.Points = corners;

        Canvas.SetLeft(myPolyline, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(myPolyline, 0);

        ObjectsCanvas.Children.Clear(); // remove any old blob polyline
        ObjectsCanvas.Children.Add(myPolyline); // add new polyline
    });
}
```

When running the application I observe imperfect overlap of the blob object (thick yellow polyline), it gets somewhat right-shifted as shown in the image below.
[image: Partial screenshot of the app when not maximized]

Observed imperfection is not due to blob detection algorithm! I verified that by drawing the polylines of very same coordinates using old-fashion GDI methods on the actual bitmap.

It gets worse when I maximize the application window, an action causing `videoPlayer` to stretch:
[image]

I tried setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties of `ObjectsCanvas` to `Stretch` but that does not help. Is there any method to align canvas exactly with the actual displayed image region?
I could get back to drawing the polylines using GDI, but I think it's a shame doing so in WPF...

Comment: Have you considered the difference between actual pixel and Device Independent Pixel When calculating the coordinates of the Polyline?

Comment: Don't put the image on a grid.  Put it on a Canvas.  Put the polyline on the same canvas

Comment: Also make sure to use correct coordinates relative to the image. In case it has DPI other than 96, bind the Width and Height of the Image element to the PixelWidth and PixelHeight of its Source, e.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414736/1136211

Comment: @emoacht thanks, I realized I had to do proper conversion to my screen DPI (240).

Comment: @Joe if I make image as a child of canvas, it doesn't resize anymore when I maximize the window.

Comment: You can write code to do that.  Use a scale transform that adjusts as the containing window's size changes -- so you'll need a SizeChanged handler.  But that would require a bit of code behind.  My point is that if you want the absolute pixel positioning for the line to match the image, they should both be on the same canvas.    You can then either apply the transform to just the canvas or individually to the image and the line's Geometry.  The former option is simple but makes line widths change with scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

So, in order to stretch your canvas up to your image size you could wrap your canvas in `ViewvBox` control and bind your `Canvas.Height` and `Canvas.Width` to the image source's `Height` and `Width` like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="MyFrame" Stretch="Uniform" />
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas
            x:Name="MyCanvas"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=MyFrame, Path=Source.Width}"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=MyFrame, Path=Source.Height}">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0" Color="White" />
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

However you need to set your `Canvas.Background` (you can make it transparent like in the example above), or `ViewvBox` will hide all of the canvas children otherwise.

Here are some screenshots of it working with a yellow polyline:

[image: TallExample]

[image: WideExample]

One more thing to note here - the coordinates of your polyline should be relative to image resolution.

Hope that helps!