How to display pixel-perfect bitmap on screen in WPF?
I need to display basic geometric shapes (line, square, ellipse, ...) in the corner of the screen with pixel precision. This means that if the line is 5 pixels long in the application, I need it to have the same number of pixels on the screen. The reason for this is that such an image is streamed to the video processing (HDMI) and it then continues to work with the individual pixels.
So far I have a WPF application that draws geometric shapes using WriteableBitmapEx and then I render this bitmap to Canvas using OnRender
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    if (_bitmap is null) return;

    var width = _bitmap.PixelWidth;
    var height = _bitmap.PixelHeight;

    drawingContext.DrawImage(_bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
}

For the Canvas I set RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" and RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
Also, the Canvas size matches the bitmap size.
But, the result is not good:
this is what I draw

the bitmap itself is OK
but the output on the screen is this

Looks like some lines are doubled based on their position. Any idea why and how to correct it?
UPDATE:
On different PC the same image looks like this


First, you should understand the difference between DIP (Device Independent Pixel) and physical pixel. Second, the pixel perfect is already accomplished by aligning the edge of line to the nearest boundaries of physical pixels. Rather, your actual issue is that the ratio of lengthes are not strictly kept the same as the original ones. Theoretically, it can only be done when the DPI is 100% or 200% and 400% ...

@emoacht You pointed me in the right direction. Just needed to set the correct DPI for the bitmap. Thanks.

You may perhaps also do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414736/1136211
